# Grammar for $L=\{a^{i+1}b^{i}c^{2j}d^je^{2j}|i,j>0\}$

Tags: formal-grammars

I'm supposed to write grammar for this language: $$L=\{a^{i+1}b^{i}c^{2j}d^je^{2j}\mid i,j>0\}$$

This is what I have so far:

$$\begin{align}
S &\to aXbY \; \\
X &\to aXb \;|\; a \\
Y &\to ccYdE \;|\; ccdE \\
Ed &\to dE \; \\
dE &\to dee \; \\
eE &\to eee \; \\
\end{align}$$

*Edit:*

Thank you for answers, I looked at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar#Example and edited my grammar:

Is this correct? Is it necessary to do
$$\begin{align}
Ed &\to dE \; \\
dE &\to dee \; \\
eE &\to eee \; \\
\end{align}$$
or can I just do
$$\begin{align}
Ed &\to dee \; \\
E &\to ee \; \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: You cannot write a context-free grammar which recognizes more than two sequences with related lengths (roughly speaking). So $a^nb^nc^n$ is not context-free, and neither is anything which closely resembles it. You have to watch out for trick questions, though :-(

Comment: Is there any grammar for this language? My task was to find grammar for this language (not specified further), but I assumed only regular and context free languages have grammar.

Comment: And $ed\to de$ is not context-free, by definition.  But there are context-sensitive grammars which will work.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar#Example for a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct.

The alternative with $E\to ee$ is incorrect, as it might generate 'ee' in between 'd's. You must first shift all the E's to the end and only then make them into $ee$.

I would generate $cc$ and $ee$ together, and play with the $D$'s, i.e., $Y\to cc YD ee$, etc. This will be slightly more simple, though equivalent.