# Grammar for $\{a^n b^n c^m d^m \mid n \geq 1, m \geq 0\}$

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers

I'm trying to understand how the construction of simple grammars works.

In my textbook, there's the following example I am supposed to find a grammar for:

> Let $L_1= \{a^n b^n c^m d^m \mid n \geq 1, m \geq 0\}$ be a language over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b,c,d\}$. Find a grammar $G = (\Sigma, N, S, P)$ - where $N$ denotes the non-terminals, $S$ the start symbol and $P$ the production rules - such that $L(G) = L_1$, i.e. the grammar $G$ generates the language $L_1$.

These were my first thoughts analyzing the problem:

- We need to have the same number of $a$'s and $b$'s
- We need to have the same number of $c$'s and $d$'s
- There needs to be at least one $a$ and one $b$
- Examples of such a string: $aabbcccddd$, $ab$, $aabbcd$

Furthermore, let $\lambda$ be the empty symbol.

The start symbol $S$ should map to something like:
$$ S \rightarrow XY$$

Then
$$X \rightarrow aZb, \; Z \rightarrow X | \lambda$$
$$Y \rightarrow cYd | \lambda$$

Would something like that work? I'm confused because the textbook presented similar grammars and the production rules almost never used the empty symbol ($\lambda$).

Is it possible to construct this grammar without using $\lambda$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always write a grammar without $\lambda$, unless the language itself includes $\lambda$. In that case, you will need the single production $S\to\lambda$ (where $S$ is the start symbol).

There's a simple algorithm for removing $\lambda$ from grammars. First, figure out which non-terminals might produce $\lambda$. (These non-terminals are called "nullable non-terminals".) Then, for each nullable non-terminal and for each production in which it occurs, add a new production which is the same but without the non-terminal. (If the non-terminal appears more than once in the same production, do this for each occurrence of the non-terminal.) Keep doing this until no more additions are possible. Then remove all of the productions with empty right-hand sides, except the empty production for the start symbol (if there is one).

Applying this algorithm to your example, we first find that $Y$ and $Z$ are nullable, while $S$ and $X$ are not. So then we need to add additional productions:

- From $X\to a Z b$, add $X\to a b$.
- From $Y\to c Y d$, add $Y\to c d$.
- From $S\to X Y$, add $S\to X$.

That gives us:

$$S\to X Y, S\to X\\
X\to a Z b, 
X\to a b \\
Z\to X,
Z\to \lambda \\
Y\to c Y d,
Y\to c d,
Y\to \lambda
$$
We then delete the two empty productions, leaving:
$$S\to X Y, S\to X\\
X\to a Z b, 
X\to a b \\
Z\to X \\
Y\to c Y d,
Y\to c d
$$
At this point, we might note that $Z$ is totally redundant. We can simplify the grammar by just substituting its right-hand side in the only place where it is used:
$$S\to X Y, S\to X\\
X\to a X b, 
X\to a b \\
Y\to c Y d,
Y\to c d
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! It's clear now. However, now I am battling with a constraint added to the problem: $L = \{a^n b^n c^m d^m \mid n \geq 1, m \geq 0, n > m\}$. I've been trying for the last two hours to include the constraint $n > m$. Now, everytime we add a $c/d$ we need to add at least one more $a/b$ but I can't recognize how we could recursively build up this string.

Comment: You can't implement that additional constraint with a context-free grammar.

Comment: Is there a rather obvious way to do it without a CFG?

Comment: Useful: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/139295/grammar-for-l-ai1bic2jdje2ji-j0. See the referenced Wikipedia article, too.

Comment: I see. So I have to generate symbols in a specific way and then use a reordering trick (rule) to ensure we generate a pair of a/b for every pair of c/d at least.

Comment: @PsychoKitten: That's roughly how you would do it with a Turing Machine, no?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Theoretical Computer Science, so I have just encountered the basics of formal languages. :)